# surjective-flat factorisation of ring homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading "The Eigenbook" by J. Bellaïche, and there is a statement in Proposition 2.4.1 that I don't know how to prove. Let $R \rightarrow R'$ be a morphism of Noetherian rings. Here is the statement in question:

> ... any morphism $R \rightarrow R'$ may be factorized as $R \rightarrow R'' \rightarrow R'$ with $R \rightarrow R''$ flat and $R'' \rightarrow R'$ surjective.

Could you please give me some references?

Comment: Geometrically you can always factor a morphism $f: X \to Y$ as $X \to X \times Y \to Y$, where the first map is the inclusion of the graph of $f$ and the second map is the projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ index the elements $R'$, so that $R' = \{r_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in I}$ as a set.

Consider the (usually massive) polynomial ring $R'' = R[x_\alpha]_{\alpha \in I }$ and the evaluation map $R'' \rightarrow R'$ mapping $x_\alpha$ to $r_\alpha$.

Clearly $R \rightarrow R''$ makes $R''$ free as an $R$-module and $R'' \rightarrow R'$ is surjective.

Note that if $R'$ is not a finite-type $R$-algebra then this does not in general give you a Noetherian $R''$.